# Almacenar datos en un ArrayList

Tags: android

Dado el siguiente código:

```
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    ArrayList<Point> casilla = new ArrayList<>();
    Point punto = new Point(x, y);
    //Plantilla
    for(int n=0; n<20; n++){
        for(int m=0; m<20; m++) {
            punto.set(x,y);
            casilla.add(punto);
            x = x + 1;
            Log.d("Casilla:", punto + "");
        }
        x = 0;
        y = y + 1;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<200;i++){
        punto = casilla.get(i);
        Log.d("Casilla:", punto + "");
    }
```

Cuando intento recuperar los datos el array solo se rellena con el último valor del bucle. ¿No se pueden almacenar valores en un bucle anidado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas agregando la misma instancia del objeto punto al `ArrayList`, por lo que sea actualizaran todos los elementos que agregues a la lista:

```
//...
Point punto = new Point(x, y);
for(int n=0; n<20; n++){
    for(int m=0; m<20; m++) {
        // se esta utilizando la misma instancia por lo que siempre agregaras el mismo
        // objeto a la lista y todos los valores seran los mismos
        punto.set(x,y);
        casilla.add(punto);
```

Debes de inicializar una instancia de la clase Point dentro del for, no fuera, para que sea independiente de las demas instancias y no se actualizen todas:

```
///...
for(int n=0; n<20; n++){
    for(int m=0; m<20; m++) {
        // iniciamos una nueva instancia de Point
        Point punto = new Point(x, y);
        punto.set(x,y);
        casilla.add(punto);

        //...
```

Answer (score -1):

En cada bucle debes agregar una nueva instancia de `Point` a tu `ArrayList`, si creas solo una el primera dato permanecerá siempre.

Debes crear una nueva instancia de `Point` en cada bucle.

```
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    ArrayList<Point> casilla = new ArrayList<>();
    Point punto = new Point(x, y);
    //Plantilla
    for(int n=0; n<20; n++){
        for(int m=0; m<20; m++) {

             //*Crea instancia de punto para un nuevo dato!
            punto = new Point(x, y); 

            //agrega datos a punto.
            punto.set(x,y);
            //Agrega nuevo punto a ArrayList.
            casilla.add(punto);
            x = x + 1;
            Log.d("Casilla:", punto + "");
        }
        x = 0;
        y = y + 1;
    }

    //Imprime datos almacenados
    for (int i=0;i<200;i++){
        punto = casilla.get(i);
        Log.d("Casilla:", punto + "");
    }
```

Comment: Esto es falso : *"si creas solo una el primera dato permanecerá siempre."* El primer dato es el punto (0,0) y no permanece en el código del autor original. De hecho ese es justo el problema que tiene el autor, que no permanece el dato. Además, esta respuesta no contribuye nada nuevo con respecto a la que ya existía 5 horas antes.

Comment: Que bien que comentas mi publicación, 
te sugiero que antes de votar positivo a las publicaciones revises y te asegures que la respuesta no sea un comentario o una edición del OP, revisa [answer]. Cuando votes negativo es de mucha ayuda a los usuarios comentar la razón para mejorar sus respuestas. Importante: Si no conoces la tecnología en cuestión lo mejor es omitir, saludos.